# Azure Custom Policy - Apply only to new resources

Tags: azure, policy

This is my policy:

```
{


"mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "in": [
            "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachineScaleSets"
          ]
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSku",
          "like": "2012*"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

I basically want to deny the deplyment of any WS2012 VMs, and it works... However, it affects already deployed resources and it denies the "Update" operations such as attaching a data disk.

Is it possible to only apply this policy when a resource is created instead? I read that this is the case with "Built-in" policies.

Answer (score 0):

Policy enforcement will be for both creation of resources and existing resources. I do not believe there is a way that you can do this for just create.